Vercel Usage Limits. When does it reset or will it reset
I want to know how exactly does vercel limits work. I am using the hobbiest plan and my bandwith says its 3mb/100gb Ik thats low but I want to know does it reset ever. I heard that it resets every month I want to confirm that, cause its been a month and nothing has changed.
I was expecting that it would reset to 0mb/100gb in the bandwith in the dashboard this month.

I use Vercel and I've got the same question.
I did some digging through their docs and found this:

As the Hobby plan is a free tier there are no billing cycles. In most cases, if you exceed your usage limits on the Hobby plan, you will have to wait until 30 days have passed before you can use the feature again.

Based on this, I think that within any given 30 days, you have to stay within the Hobby Plan usage limits. Otherwise, you will have to wait 30 days for your usage to go back to zero.
Hope this helps you and anyone else with the same question!
